# How to use ReplaceWith and put the result in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the miss of information

I have a paragraph like this

```
<p class="contenucomm12345">test 3   <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/laughing.png" alt=":laughing:" class="emoji_comm"/> <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/smile.png" alt=":smile:" class="emoji_comm" /> <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/satisfied.png" alt=":satisfied:" class="emoji_comm"/> <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/kissing_heart.png" alt=":kissing_heart:" class="emoji_comm"/></p>
```

And i want

```
<p class="contenucomm12345">test 3   :laughing: :smile: :satisfied: :kissing_heart: </p>
```

To do what i want i'm using the function below

```
 $(".contenucomm" + idcom +"  img").each(function(index, value){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).attr('alt'));
   });
```

But actually the paragraph, generated by the database is update but in the DOM

I want to put the following in an input and not the DOM.

```
<p class="contenucomm12345">test 3   :laughing: :smile: :satisfied: :kissing_heart: </p>
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Your ques isnt clear! Can you please try and be more specific with what you want

Comment: What do you mean put it in an input?  Can you please explain your desired result a bit more?

Comment: Seeing the associated HTML would help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```js
var a = $($(".contenucomm12345")[0]).text();
$("img").each(function(index, value) {
  a = a + $(this).attr('alt');
});
$("#abc").val(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="contenucomm12345">test 3 <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/laughing.png" alt=":laughing:" class="emoji_comm" /> <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/smile.png" alt=":smile:" class="emoji_comm" /> <img src="/monsite/img/emoji/satisfied.png" alt=":satisfied:" class="emoji_comm" /> <img
    src="/monsite/img/emoji/kissing_heart.png" alt=":kissing_heart:" class="emoji_comm" /></p>
<input id="abc" type="text" />
```